# What is the appropriate Machine Learning Algorithm for this scenario?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-mining, regression, bayesian-networks

I am working on a Machine Learning problem which looks like this:

Input Variables

```
 Categorical

   a

   b

   c

   d

 Continuous

   e
```

Output Variables

```
Discrete(Integers)
    v
    x
    y

Continuous
    z
```

The major issue that I am facing is that Output Variables are not totally independent of each other and there is no relation that can be established between them. That is, there is a dependence but not due to the causality (one value being high doesn't imply that the other will be high too but the chances of other being higher will improve)

An Example would be:

v - Number of Ad Impressions

x - Number of Ad Clicks

y - Number of Conversions

z - Revenue

Now, for an Ad to be clicked, it has to first appear on a search, so Click is somewhat dependent on Impression.

Again, for an Ad to be Converted, it has to be first clicked, so again Conversion is somewhat dependent on Click.

So running 4 instances of the problem predicting each of the output variables doesn't make sense to me. Infact there should be some way to predict all 4 together taking care of their implicit dependencies.

But as you can see, there won't be a direct relation, infact there would be a probability that is involved but which can't be worked out manually.

Plus the output variables are not Categorical but are in fact Discrete and Continuous.

Any inputs on how to go about solving this problem. Also guide me to existing implementations for the same and which toolkit to use to quickly implement the solution.

Just a random guess - I think this problem can be targeted by Bayesian Networks. What do you think ?

Comment: So are you trying to predict v,x,y and z given some input values a,b,c,d and e? Do you have more information on a,b,c,d an e?

Comment: a,b,c,d are categorical (range from 0-5)

and e is Continuous

What more information do you seek ?

Answer (score 0):

Bayesian Networks will do fine in your case. Your network won't be that huge either so you can live with exact inference algorithms like graph elimination or junction tree. If you decide to use BNs, then you can use Kevin Murphy's BN toolbox. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/bnt/) is a link to that. For a more general toolbox that uses Gibbs sampling for approximate Monte Carlo inference, you can use [BUGS](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/bugs/).

Edit:

As an example look at the famous sprinkler example [here](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnintro.html). For totally discrete variables, you define the conditional probability tables as in the link. For instance you say that given that today is cloudy, there is a 0.8 probability of rain. You define all probability distributions, where the graph shows the causality relations (i.e. if cloud then rain etc.) Then as query you ask to your inference algorithm questions like, given that grass was wet; was it cloudy, was it raining, was the sprinkler on and so on.

To use BNs one needs a system model that is described in terms of causality relations (Directed Acyclic Graph) and probability transitions. If you wanna learn your system parameters there are techniques like [EM algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm). However, learning the graph structure is a really hard task and supervised machine learning approaches will do better in that case.

Comment: So will it learn the Relationship Graph by itself?

And will it work even for Continuous Outputs?

Comment: Learning a Bayes Net is a difficult task. However, if you have the graph and the transition probabilities, inference algorithms will return you the posterior distribution of any input given the outputs. Continous nodes are not problematic either, given that you have valid and consistent transition probabilities.

Comment: I am really a newbie to Bayesian Net and all. Can you please tell me how to go about getting those Transition Probabilities? Maybe i am aware of the thing, but just missing out the terminologies. Any links pointing to that?

Comment: What i am really looking for is a very quick implementation of the solution. I am doing a very quick prototyping. So please don't mind my attempt to get the "cooked food" approach :D

Comment: YBE: How are transition probabilities in the context of Bayesian networks defined?